# How to type JSON results

Tags: typescript

I would like to convert this js to ts:

```
class foo{

   getSection() {
       return dataService.getSection('HOME_PAGE').then(data => {
          this.section(data.results[0]); //Error Here
    });
    }
}
```

The compile time error message is: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'void'.

`data` is a JSON result set, and `results[0]` is simple the first record.

How do I type this properly to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `dataService.getSection('HOME_PAGE')` is being inferred to return `Promise<void>` and therefore `data` is of type `void`.

Fix in your `dataService`:

```
getSection(secName: string): Promise<any>
```

Or something stronger if you don't want `any`.

(Some basic docs on annotations : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html)